# How to set UTF-8 charset in mPDF in Yii2

Tags: php, utf-8, yii2, mpdf

Is there any proper way to enable UTF characterset in yii-2 mPdf..

[image: This is what error looks like..]

Comment: Is it Kartik's library? It should be done automatically if the HTML page is using UTF-8 characterset. Check the HTML first.

Comment: using   <meta charset="UTF-8"> didnt worked... I am new in yii2, is there any yii2 compoment to set meta charset??

Comment: This is the way of doing it. Remember it needs to be placed as the first line in `<head>`.

Comment: I tried placing the code to the 1st line but it didnt worked.

Comment: Check on Kartik's website if the language you are using is supported and if there any solutions already provided.